# Extract the same page ranges from several PDFs

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

New to javascript.  I have some VBA experience.

I have 200+ documents each with about 200+ pages.  I need to extract the same series of page ranges from within each unique document.  I would like to specify the file name based in part on the filename from which the pages are being extracted (eg if the current document is called "John Smith Records", I would like pages 1-15 to take the name "John Smith" and save the file as "John Smith Files").  Thanks in advance for your help.

I've used the following as a basic guide but I'm still struggling:

```
/* Extract pages to folder */
// Regular expression used to acquire the base name of file
var re = /\.pdf$/i;
// filename is the base name of the file Acrobat is working on
var filename = this.documentFileName.replace(re, "");
try {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numPages; i = i + 2) {
        var j = i + 1;
        if (j >= this.numPages)
            j = i;
        this.extractPages({
            nStart: i,
             nEnd: j,
            cPath: "/F/temp/output/" + filename + "_" + i + ".pdf"
        });
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.println("Aborted: " + e)
}
```

Comment: You can use the Acrobat IAC-Reference and do it all in VBA using Acrobat OLE automation support (objects and methods). I may give you a small example if wanted.

Comment: That would be great!